# Keras: Missing clear_session, set_session, and get_session?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm using Keras 2.2.0 and am trying to do something like the following:

```
import keras.backend as K
K.clear_session()
sess = tf.Session()
K.set_session(sess)
...
with K.get_session() as sess:
```

However, I get errors saying `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'clear_session'`.  So it seems this functionality is no longer in `keras.backend`?

For instance, if I do `dir(keras.backend)`, I get:

```
['Function', 'NAME_SCOPE_STACK', 'Print', 'RandomStreams', 'T', 'T_softsign', '_BACKEND', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '_backend', '_config', '_config_path', '_epsilon', '_floatx', '_image_data_format', '_keras_base_dir', '_keras_dir', 'abs', 'absolute_import', 'all', 'any', 'arange', 'argmax', 'argmin', 'backend', 'batch_dot', 'batch_flatten', 'batch_get_value', 'batch_normalization', 'batch_set_value', 'bias_add', 'binary_crossentropy', 'cast', 'cast_to_floatx', 'categorical_crossentropy', 'clip', 'common', 'concatenate', 'constant', 'contextmanager', 'conv1d', 'conv2d', 'conv2d_transpose', 'conv3d', 'conv3d_transpose', 'cos', 'count_params', 'ctc_batch_cost', 'ctc_cost', 'ctc_create_skip_idxs', 'ctc_interleave_blanks', 'ctc_path_probs', 'ctc_update_log_p', 'cumprod', 'cumsum', 'defaultdict', 'depthwise_conv2d', 'division', 'dot', 'dropout', 'dtype', 'elu', 'epsilon', 'equal', 'eval', 'exp', 'expand_dims', 'eye', 'f', 'flatten', 'floatx', 'foldl', 'foldr', 'function', 'gather', 'get_uid', 'get_value', 'get_variable_shape', 'gradients', 'greater', 'greater_equal', 'hard_sigmoid', 'has_arg', 'identity', 'ifelse', 'image_data_format', 'image_dim_ordering', 'importlib', 'in_test_phase', 'in_top_k', 'in_train_phase', 'int_shape', 'is_keras_tensor', 'is_placeholder', 'is_sparse', 'is_tensor', 'json', 'l2_normalize', 'learning_phase', 'less', 'less_equal', 'local_conv1d', 'local_conv2d', 'log', 'logsumexp', 'map_fn', 'max', 'maximum', 'mean', 'min', 'minimum', 'moving_average_update', 'name_scope', 'ndim', 'normalize_batch_in_training', 'not_equal', 'np', 'one_hot', 'ones', 'ones_like', 'os', 'pattern_broadcast', 'permute_dimensions', 'placeholder', 'pool', 'pool2d', 'pool3d', 'pow', 'print_function', 'print_tensor', 'prod', 'py_all', 'py_any', 'py_slice', 'py_sum', 'random_binomial', 'random_normal', 'random_normal_variable', 'random_uniform', 'random_uniform_variable', 'relu', 'repeat', 'repeat_elements', 'reset_uids', 'reshape', 'resize_images', 'resize_volumes', 'reverse', 'rnn', 'round', 'separable_conv1d', 'separable_conv2d', 'set_epsilon', 'set_floatx', 'set_image_data_format', 'set_image_dim_ordering', 'set_learning_phase', 'set_value', 'shape', 'sigmoid', 'sign', 'sin', 'slice', 'softmax', 'softplus', 'softsign', 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 'spatial_2d_padding', 'spatial_3d_padding', 'sqrt', 'square', 'squeeze', 'stack', 'std', 'stop_gradient', 'sum', 'switch', 'sys', 'tanh', 'temporal_padding', 'th_sparse_module', 'theano', 'theano_backend', 'tile', 'to_dense', 'transpose', 'truncated_normal', 'update', 'update_add', 'update_sub', 'var', 'variable', 'zeros', 'zeros_like']
```

and don't see any of those 3 in there.

How should I be writing this code in modern Keras?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11015
Seems like it is not available any may have to downgrade

It might be that your backend is set to using Theano (I believe clear_session is only available through the Tensorflow backend with Keras). You can change these settings in your keras.json to TF and clear_session should be available to you.